# Double Taxation - New York and New Jersey

Tags: taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york, new-jersey

I have a tax situation for year 2022. Amounts given below are examples.

- **1/1/2022 to 8/8/2022**: living and working in Indiana (income `$55,000`)
- **8/9/2022 to 12/31/2022**: living in New Jersey, working in New York (income `$45,000`)

---

- Total income: `$100,000`
- IN income: `$55,000`
- NJ income: `$45,000`
- NY income: `$100,000` (because, New York requires all income to reported on W2)

---

I filed for NY non-resident tax. After standard deduction, NY will calculate tax rate based on `$90,000`. NY tax becomes `$3000`. Since I didn't earn all of income in NY, the final NY tax becomes `3000x(0.4 income factor)` = `$1200`.

**Problem**

While filing for Part-year resident NJ, it asks for NY income:

- How much of your income was double-taxed while being a resident of NJ?
- How much NY taxes did you pay?

**Questions**

- What's my double-taxed income? Is it `$45,000` or `$90,000 x 0.45` or something else? I am confused because NY considered Indiana income too.
- How much NY taxes I paid to get correct NJ credits? Is it the total amount `$1200` or a fraction of `$1200`?

Comment: To clarify, you mean that the income that you were subject to New York tax on was $45,000, but the rate of New York tax was calculated based on your worldwide income ($100,000). Is that correct?

Comment: @user102008 that is correct

Answer (score 3):

Your doubly-taxed income was $45,000, which is the amount of income that is taxable in both New York and New Jersey.

The amount of New York tax you paid on that doubly-taxed income was $1,200. Basically, the only income that was taxable in New York was that $45,000 of doubly-taxed income; therefore, the amount of New York tax on the doubly-taxed income is the total amount of New York tax paid, i.e. $1,200. The same is true of your New Jersey tax -- the only income that was taxable in New Jersey was that $45,000 of doubly-taxed income; therefore, the amount of New Jersey tax on the doubly-taxed income is the total amount of New Jersey tax paid. And you get a credit equal to the lesser of the two taxes.

Comment: One additional complication: what if NY income is $44,500 and NJ income is $45,000? NY income is $500 less because of Cafe125 employee benefit. I think in this case, double-taxed income is $44,500. Am I correct? I didn't add this in original question for simplicity.

Comment: @sam: I believe you are correct